# Modal box completely function-less..links don't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, modal-dialog

ok after 4 hours of work today I finally got a modal box that positions properly http://savenew4.info/fade.php

unfortunately, it's useless. The link to google.com doesn't work. I dunno why this is. HOw do I make the modal box functional.

Comment: I suggest you test the site on a 1080p screen, it just doesn't look right...I think your problem is z-index position though.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get this code from? A quick inspection using Firebug shows you have a `.popup:after` selector that is appending a 100% width/height element on top of the dialog, which is preventing any click-through. Remove that and the link will be clickable. I'm really not sure what you're trying to do though.

Comment: Oh, that's what it is. God damn. I was checking it out with Chrome's dev tools and wondering wtf was causing the parent element to overlap its child.